# Function for showing thumbnails for nodes with imce

Tags: media, nodes, files

I am looking for a function, to show thumbnails for nodes.
There are some sized defined in imce and I want to show on of these.

This is my current function which puts out only the large Version of the Image:

```
if (isset($content['field_image'])) {
    echo render($content['field_image']);
}
```

What would be a correct Drupal 7 conform function the show the 'medium' thumbnail in the node template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change style output in display fields settings of your content type. This will affect you render.

Also you can use [theme_image_style](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/theme_image_style/7) function to set your image style

Url of image you can find in `$content['field_image']['und'][0]['uri']`